# Data conversion from known data

Tags: data-modeling

I am trying to add a function to a software (not written by me, no sources available) in which a byte string seems to be convertet somehow:

I am reading an ID from a RFID token: as Bytes: 
`52 55 48 48 69 54 52 65 54 65` this ID is written in the database as `57770346`.

Not just the entries are different, the length is, too. Maybe the first entrys are cut off.

How could the function look like? How could i find it?

Here is some additional data:

1. `52 55 48 48 69 54 52 65 54 65  ->  57770346`
2. `52 55 48 48 69 53 68 67 51 49  ->  57742129`
3. `48 49 48 52 68 70 57 69 65 68  ->  76731309`

Comment: What type is the DB field?

Comment: it's a string in the DB (bad software by the way!)

Answer (score 1):

Found it myself:

1. BIN to ASCII
2. ASCII as HEX to INT

(first 4 characters are missing in the DB)

I'm embarrassed...